# Some fontawesome5 icons not working in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, overleaf, fontawesome

I'm trying to use fontawesome5 package in LaTeX. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\faKey
\faOrcid
\end{document}
```

The first command (`\faKey`) works, but the second (`\faOrcid`) doesn't. In fact, other commands like `\faLinkedIn` are also not working. I tried compiling with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` as well as `xelatex` on Overleaf, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: `\faOrcid` is not part of `fontawesome` (if I'm not mistaken).  Try `academicons` and `\aiOrcid` instead.

Comment: I can compile your document fine with XeLaTeX on my computer, but not on Overleaf.

Comment: @HenriMenke [this](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf) fontawesome5 documentation, `\faOrcid` seems to be included.

Comment: @Vincent I'm using Overleaf for compiling - perhaps this is an Overleaf issue after all?

Comment: @Dr.PrasannaDate It looks like it is indeed.

Comment: @Dr.PrasannaDate Then they have added it recently.  It's probably not yet available on Overleaf.  Just try `academicons` in the meantime.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ The current version of `fontawesome5` indeed doesn't include `\faOrcid` nor `\faLinkedIn` yet, sorry!

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you could download a copy of the font into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the above comments suggest, some `fontawesome5` icons like `\faOrcid` and `\faLinkedIn` have not been added to Overleaf yet and can't be used at the moment. Using `academicons` seems like the best work around in the meanwhile.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\faKey
\aiOrcid
\end{document}
```